# How do I make @WebMvcTest pickup WebMvcConfigurer classes from custom starters?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm building a custom starter library which registers an ObjectMapper in a WebMvcConfigurer class. One of the settings on this ObjectMapper is an Instant serialization format.

When I use @SpringBootTest with @AutoConfigureMockMvc the configured ObjectMapper is picked up, and everything works as expected. However the same assertions using @WebMvcTest fail. It seems like the WebMvcConfigurer class is not being picked up in the @WebMvcTest autoconfiguration, although the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) state that it should be picked up.

Is there a way to extend the autoconfiguration for WebMvcTest's without having to resort to putting @Import with every @WebMvcTest annotation?

[code example](https://github.com/stevenvanophem/mockmvctest-with-custom-starter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to what you have done to include your starter’s configuration in the main auto-configuration, you can include a configuration class in a particular test slice by adding an entry to `spring.factories`. In this case, you should use the key `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureWebMvc`.

If you look at the [Spring Boot source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/c7c3afdf60da9d8a6003cd5e51d43a5e5bc4d57e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories#L133) you can see that this is how Boot’s Jackson auto-configuration is included, for example.