# In Spring Boot, how do I enable a @ControllerAdvice from a starter during a @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a class `MyExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ResponseBody` to handle Exceptions, as it is a common practice in Spring Boot.

Now I moved this class to a starter, that I include in several projects, so they all use the same basic exception handling. This works fine, when I start the Spring Boot application normally.

When I execute a test annotated with:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
```

The ControllerAdvice from the starter is not activated, so I can't test my error responses.

When I create a subclass of `MyExceptionHandler` in my project and annotate that class with `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ResponseBody`, everything works fine.

How can I ensure, that during my test, the ControllerAdvice from the starter is activated?

Comment: can you try this`@Import(YourControllerAdvice.class) `

Comment: Yes. @Import works.
What I don't really like about this is, that I have to add something to every test to make it work. A general solution would be much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way.
Spring explicitly supports auto configuration for AutoConfigureWebMvc.
You can add a key to /META-INF/spring.factories:

org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureWebMvc=...

Also see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247057/2936509

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
```

This line is telling the test what specifically to use.  Other controllers are not added to the context. `@ControllerAdvice` is a `@Component` so it is likely also not added to the context.

You should remove this specification, or add the `@ControllerAdvice` class you want to test as well.

The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/api/) talks about this in the 'controllers' value and 'value' value section.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!
Adding the advice as another "controller" in the @WebMvcTest does not work.
Interestingly, when the ControllerAdvice is in the project itself, it is used. It's only not used, when it's coming from a spring-boot-starter.

Comment: The documentation I find usually also states, that ControllerAdvices are added automatically, when `@WebMvcTest` is used. e.g.
"By default only `@Controller` (when no explicit controllers are defined), `@ControllerAdvice` and WebMvcConfigurer beans are included."